# Can a party demand you not record their phone call?

Tags: canada, recording, phonecall

To my understanding call recording is legal in Canada, even if the other person isn't aware of it. I am going through arbitration, and someone I spoke with said "there is to be no recording of this or any other calls". Must I follow this instruction? If someone expressly states they do not wish to be recorded, is recording the conversation illegal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it legal to record a business call in Canada?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/is-it-legal-to-record-a-business-call-in-canada), where the accepted answer clearly explains Canadian law on recording phone calls without permission of all parties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> someone I spoke with said "there is to be no recording of this or any other calls". Must I follow this instruction?

Although, in Canada, there is no requirement on you to obtain consent to make recording, this explicit objection creates a hurdle. If you simply ignore the objection and record the conversation anyway without letting the objecting party know,  you may give them a ground for a claim under the [breach of confidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breach_of_confidence_in_English_law) doctrine.

The safest move would be to reply:

> No. There **will be** recording of this and any other calls.

It will be then up to them to hang up. If they don't, they lose all grounds for any claims.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, if someone objects to a call being recorded, their sole recourse is to end the call. If it is a two-party state the person recording must notify the other parties, and if they continue the call after being notified, they have consented, even if they object verbally. In a one-part state, the party making the recording need not notify the other parties.

Canada has a 1-party rule, but I am not sure if an explicit objection requires the person recording to either stop recording, or notify the other parties.